# permalinks with id and slug (but id routing)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My Stage:
Using PHP 7.2
WordPress 5.2.4

I want my permalink to be accessable via post/id and title slug like:

```
example-page.com/post_id/
```

and

```
example-page.com/post_id/post_title
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:
URL shoud be show title slug, but only query the page by ID in the form of /10/this-is-the-title-slug

What i have to enter in functions.php or WordPress permalinks settings?

Answer (score 1):

in your case it should be:

`/%post_id%/%postname%/`

Comment: Great, thx!
How i can add meta_field name to permalinks settings? So i have metafield with id in metafield of post. I wanna use it instead of %post_id%

Comment: How you created the metafields? do you tried just putting in the %meta_field_id%? i used this syntax for cmb2 metaboxes

Comment: i used this snippet in my functions.php to create metafield in post:
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_discount_meta' );
 
function add_discount_meta( $post_id )
{
 
        {
 global $post;
             update_post_meta( $post_id, 'metafieldname', $post_id );
        }
 
}

Comment: Hmm, does this work?   function custom_meta_permalink( $link, $post ){
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metafieldname', true );
  if( empty( $post_meta ) || !is_string( $post_meta ) )
    $post_meta = '';
  $link = str_replace( '!!custom_field_placeholder!!', $post_meta, $link );
  return $link;
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_meta_permalink', 10, 2 ); and call the link via /%postname%/!!custom_field_placeholder!!/   (not tested this!)

Comment: Entered in permalinks: /%postname%/!!custom_field_placeholder!!
in functions.php i entered your code. When i open link i get doublicate value of metafield: domain.de/title-value-value
Why value is twice shown in the end of the url?

Comment: try this pls :D function custom_meta_permalink( $link, $post ){ $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metafieldname', false ); if( empty( $post_meta ) || !is_string( $post_meta ) ) $post_meta = ''; $link = str_replace( '!!custom_field_placeholder!!', $post_meta, $link ); return $link; } add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_meta_permalink', 10, 2 );

Comment: Entered in permalinks: /%postname%/!!custom_field_placeholder!!
Then add your new code to functions.php
metafieldname is: metafieldname
Now clicked on post. Url is: domain.de/title/
So value is not added to url like :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202189/discussion-between-lvollmer-and-tommy).